# React Typescript Custom Hooks: Property 'prop_name' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to learn React and React Hooks. I have created custom hook that lives in another file: `CustomHook.ts`. I am using it in my `ContactForm.tsx`. The problem I am having is inside each `value={inputs.property}` in the `<input />` tags. Typescript is unable to resolve the types of each `inputs._propertyName`.

I have defined an interface `IContact` that defines the types I would like to use. I am NOT currently using this interface as I don't know where to put it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error:

```
ERROR in /jefthimi/src/components/Contact/ContactForm.tsx(35,31)
      TS2339: Property 'subject' does not exist on type '{}'.
ERROR in /jefthimi/src/components/Contact/ContactForm.tsx(46,31)
      TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
ERROR in /jefthimi/src/components/Contact/ContactForm.tsx(57,31)
      TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
ERROR in /jefthimi/src/components/Contact/ContactForm.tsx(68,31)
      TS2339: Property 'comments' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

ContactForm.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './ContactForm.scss';
import useContactForm from './CustomHook';

interface IContact {
  subject: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  comments: string;
}

const message = (inputs: any) => {
  alert(`Message Sent!
  Subject: ${inputs.subject}
  Sender: ${inputs.email}
  Name: ${inputs.name}
  Comments: ${inputs.comments}`);
};

const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useContactForm(message);

export default class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactForm_container">
        <div className="contactForm_inner">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-group">
              <label htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
              <input
                id="subject"
                name="subject"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={inputs.subject}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
              <input
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={inputs.email}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
              <input
                id="name"
                name="name"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={inputs.name}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <label htmlFor="comments">Comments</label>
              <textarea
                name="comments"
                id="comments"
                rows={10}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                value={inputs.comments}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="controls">
              <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CustomHook.ts

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

/*
This is a Custom React Hook that handles our form submission
*/

const useContactForm = (callback) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    callback();
  };
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setInputs((inputs) => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  };
  return {
    handleSubmit,
    handleInputChange,
    inputs
  };
};

export default useContactForm;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the initial state for `inputs` in CustomHook.ts is `{}`. Then you are trying to render `inputs.subject`, `inputs.email`, `inputs.name` and `inputs.comments`. These properties do not exist on the empty object `{}`, which is what the error messages are telling you.

Let's start with some basics. You have `IContact`, but you don't know what to do with it. You should be using it to type the data anywhere you expect that signature. To start with, the `message` callback.

```js
const message = (inputs: IContact) => {
    alert(`Message Sent!
    Subject: ${inputs.subject}
    Sender: ${inputs.email}
    Name: ${inputs.name}
    Comments: ${inputs.comments}`);
};
```

How about the `useContactForm` hook? Well, you could, but I don't think I would recommend it. When I look at that hook, I don't see anything inside of it that references `IContact`. In this case, the hook is more **generic**.

If only there was some way of adding typing that was more **generic**...

Well, there is. What we want to do is be able to pass in a type to use as the typing for other objects.

```js
const useContactForm = <T>(callback: (state: T) => void) => {
    //...code
}
```

Here, I added `<T>` to the front of the arrow function parameters. I also typed the callback as `(value: T) => void` to indicate the callback should accept a type of `T` as a parameter and not return anything.

Now, we need to type the `useState` function.

```js
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<T>({});
```

Uh-oh. `{}` doesn't match `T`. We need an initial state of type `T`. Since `T` is being passed in, our initial state will need to be as well.

```js
const useContactForm = <T>(callback: (state: T) => void, initialState: T) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<T>(initialState);
    // ...code
}
```

And pass it in.

```js
    const {inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit} = useContactForm(message, {
        subject: '',
        email: '',
        name: '',
        comments: '',
    });
```

Okay. And that's basically how that needs to get handled. **However, there are several other issues with the code and use of both TypeScript and Hooks.**

1. You need more typings. The event parameters in the event handlers should have types. e.g. `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>`
2. You are passing a function into `setInputs` instead of new state.
3. You call the `callback` in `handleSubmit` with no arguments, but the `message` callback is clearly looking for an `IContact`.
4. You are trying to use hooks in a class component instead of a functional one. You need to change the class component to a function and put the call to your custom hook inside of the function.

Here is some working code.

ContactForm.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import './ContactForm.scss';
import useContactForm from './CustomHook';

interface IContact {
    subject: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    comments: string;
}

const message = (inputs: IContact) => {
    alert(`Message Sent!
  Subject: ${inputs.subject}
  Sender: ${inputs.email}
  Name: ${inputs.name}
  Comments: ${inputs.comments}`);
};

export default () => {
    const {inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit} = useContactForm(message, {
        subject: '',
        email: '',
        name: '',
        comments: '',
    });

    return (
        <div className="contactForm_container">
            <div className="contactForm_inner">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <label htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
                        <input
                            id="subject"
                            name="subject"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            value={inputs.subject}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
                        <input
                            id="email"
                            name="email"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            value={inputs.email}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
                        <input
                            id="name"
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            value={inputs.name}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <label htmlFor="comments">Comments</label>
                        <textarea
                            name="comments"
                            id="comments"
                            rows={10}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            value={inputs.comments}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="controls">
                        <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

CustomHook.ts

```
import React, {useState, FormEvent, ChangeEvent} from 'react';

/*
This is a Custom React Hook that handles our form submission
*/

const useContactForm = <T>(callback: (state: T) => void, initialState: T) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<T>(initialState);

    const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        callback(inputs);
    };
    const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        event.persist();
        setInputs({
            ...inputs,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    return {
        handleSubmit,
        handleInputChange,
        inputs,
    };
};

export default useContactForm;
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far. It makes our Hook generic so that we can use it for different forms. I feel that I understand generics in Typescript a little bit more. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution is to define an interface that contains our Message properties, then create a default Message object that has initialized fields.

```
interface IMessage {
  subject: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  comments: string;
}

const message: IMessage = {
  subject: '',
  email: '',
  name: '',
  comments: ''
};
```

We then setState with this initialized object.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(message);
```

Comment: If you define `[key: string]: string;` it won't warn you if you try to access fields that doesn't exist on the interface

Comment: @AsafAviv Good point. This will ruin the point of using Typescript in the first place.

Comment: You will just need to use the original `interface` with `const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<IContact>({ Subject: 'me', Sender: 'you', ...rest })` and you will be good to go

Comment: @AsafAviv updated the solution. The code works and we have our types within our .tsx render method. Thank you for your input!